# Convert a list of URLs to a Tree

Tags: java, swing, sitemap, jtree

Just to be sure I'm not reinventing the wheel, I want to see if there is some known algorithm, class, or something that can help me solve my problem. I have a huge list of URLs from an application. I'd like to feed those URLs into a tree to create a sitemap-like data structure.

It seems that something like this may have done before. However, everything I see from my searches appears to do it from xml to tree. Ideally I'd like to have answer in Java, but I'm sure I could translate it to Java myself if necessary. If I need to do it myself, I'd probablty take each URL and break them into indexes.

```
[root]        [0]  [1]  [1] -file
wwe.site.com/dir1/dir2/file.html
[root]        [0]  [1]  [1]
www.site.com/dirabc/dir2/file.html
```

So, I'd parse each url into offsets `[0], [1], [2], …` etc., and those be depth down in tree where to add them. That was at least my initial plan. I'm open to any and all suggestions!

Comment: Your favorite search engine is a good place to start looking for things to prevent you from reinventing the wheel. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You could define your UrlTree as nested HashMaps

```
public class UrlTree {

  private final Map<String, UrlTree> branches = new HashMap<String, UrlTree>();

  public void add(String[] tokens, int i) {
    if (i >= tokens.length) {
      return;
    }

    final String token = tokens[i];

    UrlTree branch = branches.get(token);

    if (branch == null) {
      branch = new UrlTree();
      branches.put(token, branch);
    }

    branch.add(tokens, i + 1);
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement [`TreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) in a way that reflects the hierarchy of your observed directory structure. [`FileTreeModel`](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-) is an example, and [`ac.Name`](http://applecommander.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/applecommander/AppleCommander/src/com/webcodepro/applecommander/ui/ac.java?revision=1.45&view=markup) is a simple class that parses paths for a vintage file system. See also [*How to Use Trees*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html). An instance of NetBeans `Outline`, illustrated [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692), would make a nice alternative view.